# Presentation that shows how to use lualatex to make a presentation

Tags: beamer, listings, luatex

In my presentation, I would like to have a listings environment that shows how to make a presentation. 
So far I have found that, when using `listings` in a presentation, we should pass the option `fragile` to the frame we want use the `listings` environment in. 
I then thought that the following would work (compiling with lualatex):

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{Minimum Working Example}
        \begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{I am the title of this slide!}
        I am some body text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives lua a panic attack:

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (object in use)

The first few latex errors are:

> ./test.tex:14: Missing } inserted. 
>   
>   }
>   l.14    \end{frame}
>
> ./test.tex:14: LaTeX Error: \begin{lstlisting} on input line 2 ended by \end{be
>   amer@framepauses}.
>
> ./test.tex:14: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

When commenting out the lines `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` it compiles fine, as can be seen in the picture below.

[image: output]

Googling this I didn't get very far, mostly ending up on questions that had as answer that we should not forget to pass `fragile` to the frame when using `listings`. 
The difference between those questions and this one is that I am trying to put a frame in a listing, besides having a listing in a frame.

Comment: This problem also occurs with `pdflatex` and `xelatex` with the same LaTeX error.

Comment: Put your example in an external file and use \lstinputlisting. The inner \end{frame} confuses beamer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another option is to use `[containsverbatim]`:

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[containsverbatim]
    \frametitle{Minimum Working Example}
        \begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{I am the title of this slide!}
        I am some body text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981008/latex-issue-with-beamer-and-listings.

Comment: This is also more intuitive than `fragile`.

Answer (score 12):

As a workaround you can apply the example from page 62 of the beamer user guide:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\newenvironment{slide}
    {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=slide]}
    {\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{slide}
    \frametitle{Minimum Working Example}
        \begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{I am the title of this slide!}
        I am some body text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{slide}
\end{document}
```